# Digital Ocean Load Balancer, can't use doctl to modify load balancer rules

Tags: load-balancing, digital-ocean

I have a managed kubernetes environment on Digital Ocean.  It has a load balancer.  I am trying to assign the target_port to tcp:3000.

I want the outside port to be tcp:80, and the inside port to be tcp:3000.
Kubernetes is new to my, my only frame of reference is configuring nginx reverse proxy.

Here are the current forwarding-rules:

```
entry_protocol:tcp,
entry_port:80,
target_protocol:tcp,
target_port:32726,
certificate_id:,
tls_passthrough:false
```

This is the command I am trying to use to set the target_port rules
`doctl compute load-balancer add-forwarding-rules <LB_ID> --forwarding-rules target_port:30000`

Error:
`Error: POST https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/load_balancers/<LB_ID>/forwarding_rules: 422 (request "") forwarding rule entry port must be between 1 and 65535`

I've also tried with the protocol name
`doctl compute load-balancer add-forwarding-rules <LB_ID> --forwarding-rules target_protocol:tcp,target_port:30000`

Error:
`Error: POST https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/load_balancers/<LB_ID>/forwarding_rules: 422 (request "") protocols are not on the same network layer`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add a rule for an entry port where one already existed. So, I removed the rule that was there for entry port 80 and added another one.  I also had to add a placeholder rule (not shown) so that one was always in place or the doctl threw an error.

removed forwarding rules
`doctl compute load-balancer remove-forwarding-rules <LB> --forwarding-rules entry_protocol:tcp,entry_port:80,target_protocol:tcp,target_port:32726`

added new one
`doctl compute load-balancer add-forwarding-rules <LB_ID> --forwarding-rules entry_protocol:tcp,entry_port:80,target_protocol:tcp,target_port:3000`